# SQL Server - Unique index vs Unique constraint - Re. Duplicate values

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint, unique-index

A **unique index** ensures that the values in the index key columns are unique.
A **unique constraint**  guarantees that no duplicate values can be inserted into the column(s) on which the constraint is created. When a unique constraint is created a corresponding unique index is automatically created on the column(s).

**Questions**:

1. Can duplicate values be inserted if we have a unique index on a column and no unique constraint?
2. What about existing duplicates in any on the column - will it allow to create unique index or unique constraint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can duplicate values be inserted if we have a unique index on a column
> and no unique constraint?

Generally, duplicate values cannot be inserted and an error is raised when a unique index exists on the column. The exceptions are:

1. Index was created with the [`IGNORE_DUP_KEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-index-option-transact-sql) option. No error is raised and the insert is ignored.
2. The non-clustered index is filtered such that the duplicate value does not satisfy the index `WHERE` clause. The row is inserted but not reflected in the non-clustered index.

> What about existing duplicates in any on the column - will it allow to
> create unique index or unique constraint?

No, with the exception of the filtered index mentioned above.

Comment: Just to clarify, using `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` does not allow duplicate values to exist in the index. A unique index never has duplicate values.  Instead `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` simply causes attempts to insert duplicate values to be ignored (with a warning message) instead of causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can duplicate values be inserted if we have a unique index on a column and no unique constraint?

No, the values of the columns within the index must create a unique set of data within that index.

2. What about existing duplicates in any on the column - will it allow to create unique index or unique constraint?

No, you cannot create a Unique Index on a table that has duplicate values.

This easiest way to have found this out would be to try (I suggest for things like that doing so, it's a great way of learning):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (SomeInt int, AnotherInt int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeInt,
                           AnotherInt)
VALUES (1,1),
       (1,2),
       (2,1);
GO
--Create a unique index on a column with duplicate values
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_SomeInt ON dbo.SomeTable(SomeInt); --fails
GO
--Create a unique index on the 2 columns, as they are unique
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_Some_AnotherInt ON dbo.SomeTable(SomeInt, AnotherInt); --Succeeds
GO
--Try to insert a duplicate value
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeInt,
                           AnotherInt)
VALUES(2,1); --fails
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

One potentially unintuitive scenario that confused me at first: [postgres does not treat `NULL` values as equal.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html#:%7E:text=When%20an%20index%20is%20declared,are%20equal%20in%20multiple%20rows.) If your table looked like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|id     |a      |b      |
+-------+-------+-------+
|1      |0      |NULL   |
|2      |0      |NULL   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

You could still add a unique index on columns `a` and `b`. According to Postgres, row with id `1` and row with id `2` have the same value for column `a`, but different values for column `b`

Comment: Same for mysql / mariadb